# How to load php DS namespace in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I have installed [php-ds](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.ds.php) extension as shown [here](https://github.com/php-ds/extension). But I am unable to Load the DS namespace in PhpStorm.

How can I do this?

Comment: You need stub files in order for PhpStorm to understand what DS offers (classes/functions/etc). Stub file is basically a PHP version of that -- just "declaration/documentation" part -- e.g. function declarations but with empty bodies. You can either make your own ... or find some existing ones (if somebody else did it already, of course). A bit more on stub files in general: 1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/15775431/783119 2) http://stackoverflow.com/a/30329412/783119

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need **stub files** in order for PhpStorm to understand what DS (a PHP extension written in C) offers (classes/functions/etc).

Stub file is basically a PHP version of that -- just "declaration/documentation" part -- e.g. function declarations but with empty bodies. You can either make your own ... or find some existing ones (if somebody else did it already, of course).

A bit more on stub files in general:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775431/783119
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/30329412/783119

---

So .. basically what you need is [php-ds/polyfill](https://github.com/php-ds/polyfill) -- *"You should also include the polyfill in your project for compatibility and IDE integration"* .

IDE will read such files and will understand what real DS extension has to offer/what it does (type of parameters/returns/etc).