# How to get PhpStorm to show PHPDoc for a C++ library?

Tags: phpstorm, php-extension, phpdoc

I've written a PHP extension in C++ and I'd like PhpStorm to display a PHPDocs tooltip on <kbd>Ctrl + Q</kbd> like it does for native PHP methods. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/43737284/783119 . Basically, you need to create a stub file for your library (a PHP version of your class/function/constants etc -- just structure with docs -- no real function body or alike). You can see how it looks for ANY extension that PhpStorm already supports: just `Ctlr+Click` on on standard class or function (or check live at https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs).

Comment: If you have a lot of documentation to read (e.g. examples, use cases etc) -- include `@link` tag for such class/method/etc. Otherwise just use PHPDoc and add (detailed) description for every class/method/parameter. If your function returns or parameter accepts specific types only -- be specific about that. Consider supporting PHPStan and Psalm style tags as well for those who use those tools (e.g. for collections/generics and other stuff that PHPDoc does not support).

Comment: Consider also providing `.phpstorm.meta` file -- more advanced/dynamic stuff (e.g. can limit values are acceptable for this parameter; what the actual return type would be if it depends on input parameter etc). See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/ide-advanced-metadata.html