# Stats Pecl package PhpStorm not found via code completion

Tags: php, statistics, phpstorm, pecl

I have seen this question and added the package via composer, but to no avail:

[PhpStorm: How to add method stubs from a PECL library that PhpStorm doesn't currently support?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328805/phpstorm-how-to-add-method-stubs-from-a-pecl-library-that-phpstorm-doesnt-curr)

(It does appear in the include entry in the settings).

The stats package is also not listed on the main display of the GitHub entry.

The package had been installed via pecl and is up and running and also works; it is already included in my code. It is only the IDE that begs to differ.

How do I include this library in such a way as to have full code coverage in PhpStorm.

**Edit:**
I am currently using this function: `stats_standard_deviation`. It works, but PhpStorm lists it as 'cannot find it'.

Comment: Screenshots of what you did exactly. As well as what files you have put there. Right now I have a feeling that you have misread the question / misunderstood it.

Comment: I will not post my code online. All you need to know is this: The package had been installed via pecl and is up and running and also works; it is already included in my code. It is only the IDE that begs to differ.

How do I include this library in such a way as to have full code coverage in PhpStorm.

Comment: I have no idea what you have put there and therefore cannot say for sure what needs to be done. So far it sounds like you have put NON PHP code... which is useless for PhpStorm. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15775431/783119 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/35923482/783119

Comment: I have a fully operational cms here. I have installed the library via pecl. I have included some of the functions of pecls stats in my code and all runs fine and I have no errors whatsoever. The results are correct. The things that does not work is the IDE, which is unable to find the proper methods: stats_standard_deviation,stats_absolute_deviation. _There_ lies the problem. Only there and nowhere else. How do I fix this? I like to have full code coverage and editor coverage.

Comment: Try reading the 2 links I gave you + the one you have linked yourself once more. The answer is there (as per my understanding of your situation, based on the info you have provided so far). It resolved issue for those who asked those questions .. so it's definitely a correct working solution. PhpStorm itself does exactly the same thing.

Comment: Sorry that I have asked ... really. Your comments are just useless and a waste of my time. That would not solve my issue, but creating random files or code (stubs or fragments )somewhere in my cms, whose sole purpose would be to bloat my code without adding anything to it. That would not be a solution, that would be a diversion from it; sadly I cannot down vote your comments, because that would actually be required. All you had to say was: no, this is not supported by the IDE, you need to create stubs yourself or find your own intermediary "solution".

Comment: PhpStorm does not care about PECL code itself (either source C or final binary `.dll`/`.so` file) -- it cannot read those files. It needs a **stub** file that IDE can parse (a PHP version of your pecl library). _That's how whole standard PHP library is supported -- all classes/functions/constants. See for yourself -- https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs. So yes -- if you want PhpStorm to properly recognize those functions and offer in code completion etc -- you need to make such stub file. Just like Phalcon framework does: https://phalconphp.com/en/download/stubs